# React Link cant open heroku url

Tags: reactjs, heroku, hyperlink, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a Link in my react project to open the other project that was deployed with Heroku but somehow when I click the link, the page's url becomes http://localhost:3000/mytrellos.herokuapp.com instead of https://mytrellos.herokuapp.com/ So the page cant be rendered. Could anyone please advise what the problem is?
Here is my code:

````
       <Link to="mytrellos.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
            Visit Website
            </Link>
```
````

Comment: [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) only "Provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application." so no linking to external URLs, use an anchor (`<a />`) tag for this. A possible solution is to create your own custom "Link" component that renders one or the other depending on the path prefix, i.e. if it starts with "https://".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to add the protocol of the link too if not it would append the link url to the current windows url.

So `<a href="mytrellos.herokuapp.com/"></a>` goes to `http://localhost:3000/mytrellos.herokuapp.com`

And you could just use a normal anchor tag for this since the purpose for this is just to open a link in new tab

```
<a href="https://mytrellos.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
   Visit Website
</a>
```

and this should work